# Are these the only real fixed points of the polynomials $(f_n)_{n\ge 1}$ given by $f_1=X^2-1$ and $f_{n+1}=f_n^2-1$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, recurrence-relations, fixed-points

Define a sequence of polynomials with integer coefficients $(f_n)_{n\ge 1}$ by $f_1 = X^2-1$ and
$$f_{n+1}=f_n^2-1.$$
Now, for any $n$, what are the $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $f_n(x)=x$?

There are some obvious ones. Both roots of $X^2-X-1$ are fixed points of all $f_n$, and when $n$ is even, $0$ and $-1$ are as well. Computations with some (very) small values of $n$ suggest these are the only ones; is this correct? What if in the recursion we take a negative real number other than $-1$?

**Edit:** I believe that if we have a 'cycle' of $k$ distinct values $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ with $\alpha_{i+1}=\alpha_i^2-1$ and $\alpha_k^2-1=\alpha_1$, then the polynomial $g:=\prod_{i=1}^k(X-\alpha_i)$ satisfies $g(X^2-1)=(-1)^kg(X)g(-X)$. In particular, $g(X)\mid g(X^2-1)$, which might be useful.

Comment: I feel like this should be well-known, but I'm not finding any good references on it. This should be intimately tied with the classic study of quadratic Julia/Fatou sets; unfortunately since your $f$ isn't conjugate to anything substantially 'cleaner' there isn't an easy answer by transforming $f$, but I feel like periodic points of Julia iterations is a well-studied topic...

Comment: Some random thoughts: there can clearly be no fixed points in $0\lt x\lt 1$; $f_n(x)\lt 0$ for all $n$ and all $x$ in that range. You should be able to show that there can only be one fixed point in $1\lt x$ by derivative arguments, which leaves $-1\lt x\lt 0$. You can examine the cases of odd and even $n$ separately, and again I feel like derivative-based arguments may be enough to show at most one intersection point in that range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to define $f(x)=x^2-1$ so that your $f_n(x)$ are $f^{\circ n}(x) = f\left (f^{\circ(n-1)}(x)\right)$, the $n$-fold composition of $f$.

Now, for $0\leq x\lt \phi$ we have $f(x)\lt x$ and for $x\gt\phi$ we have $f(x)\gt x$, so by induction (also using the fact that $-1\lt f(x)\lt 0$ for $-1\lt x\lt 0$) the only positive fixed point of $f^{\circ n}$ is $\phi$. Since $f(x)\geq -1$ for all $x$, any remaining fixed points must be in $[-1, 0]$.

By the composition rule for derivatives, we have $\dfrac{d}{dx}f^{\circ n}(x)$ $=\dfrac{d}{dx}f\left(f^{\circ (n-1)}(x)\right)$ $=f'\left(f^{\circ(n-1)}(x)\right)\dfrac{d}{dx}f^{\circ(n-1)}(x)$; induction then gives that this is $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}f'\left(f^{\circ i}(x)\right)$. Since $f'(x)=2x$, this is just $2^n\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}f^{\circ i}(x)$ . Now, if $n$ is odd then this product must be less than zero (each term in it is negative), so $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(f^{\circ n}(x)-x\right)\lt 0$; this, combined with the values of $f^{\circ n}(-1)=0$ and $f^{\circ n}(0)=-1$ establishes that there's exactly one fixed point in the interval.

Finally, the case of $n$ even can be settled similarly to the case $x\gt 0$; for $-1\lt x\lt -\phi^{-1}$ we have $f^{\circ 2}(x)\lt x$ and for $-\phi^{-1}\lt x\lt 0$, $f^{\circ 2}(x)\gt x$, so induction yields $f^{\circ 2i}(x)=x$ only for $x=-\phi^{-1}$ in this range.

It's also pretty straightforward, using the above, to characterize the fixed points; both $-1$ and $0$ are attracting fixed points of $f^{\circ 2}()$ whereas $\phi$ and $-\phi^{-1}$ are repulsing fixed points of $f()$. In other words, for $-1\leq x\lt\phi$, iterating $f()$ converges to the cycle $\langle -1, 0\rangle$; for $x\gt\phi$, iterating $f()$ diverges. (The basin of attraction is somewhat larger than this, of course; in fact, the iterations converge to the cycle for exactly $x\in (-\phi, \phi)$. )

---

The case for general $c$ in $f_c(x)=x^2-c$ gets substantially more complicated, specifically as $c$ goes from $1$ to $2$. In fact, we can see that $c=1$ is a somewhat unusual point by studying convergence around the fixed cycle $\langle 0,1\rangle$. Consider a point $x=\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$; then after one iteration this goes to $\epsilon^2-1$ and after two this goes to $(\epsilon^2-1)^2-1=\epsilon^4-2\epsilon^2$. Since $\epsilon$ is small we can throw out the $\epsilon^4$ term and say that $f_1^{\circ 2}()$ maps $\epsilon$ to $-2\epsilon^2+o(\epsilon^2)$. But this is what's known as *superlinear* convergence; 'generically' near a fixed point, we would expect to have some constant $M$ such that $f_c^{\circ 2}()$ affects points around a fixed point $x_f$ by sending $x_f+\epsilon$ to $x_f+M\epsilon+o(\epsilon)$; the fixed point is then attracting if $|M|\lt 1$ and repelling if $|M|\gt 1$. The fact that our $M$ here is zero is a sign that we're not at a generic value of $c$. In fact, this $c$ is the exact center of the interval $(3/4, 5/4)$ where the dynamics of $f_c$ feature a period-2 cycle. For $c$ slightly larger than $5/4$, the cycle is instead period 4; e.g., if we look at $c=1.3$ then [the iteration converges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NestList%5B%23%5E2-1.3+%26%2C+-1%2C+40%5D) to a length-4 cycle roughly at $\langle -1.149, 0.019, -1.3, 0.389\rangle$.

These dynamics can be mapped to various features of the Mandelbrot set; the region $c\in(3/4, 5/4)$ where the iteration converges to a $2$-cycle corresponds exactly to the first circular bulb to the left of the main cardioid. They've also been studied even more extensively in another guise: by taking $x_n=ay_n+b$ we can write $ay_{n+1}+b$ $= x_{n+1}=x_n^2+c$ $=a^2y_n^2+2aby_n+b^2+c$, or on subtracting $b$ from both sides and dividing by $a$, $y_{n+1} = ay_n^2+2by_n+(b^2-b+c)/a$. Now, taking $b$ such that $b^2=b-c$ lets us eliminate the constant term and write $y_{n+1}=ay_n^2+2by_n$; further taking $a=-2b$ this can be written as $y_{n+1}=ay_n^2-ay_n$ $=ay_n(1-y_n)$. This reparametrization lets us look at the interval $y\in [0,1]$ specifically and iterations within this interval (as long as $a\leq 4$; for larger $a$ the map no longer carries the interval $[0,1]$ to a subset of itself and all bets are off). In this form, it's known as the [*Logistic Map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) and it's been very widely studied, including the famous 'bifurcation diagram' you may have seen that shows how the attracting fixed points/fixed cycles change as $a$ increases towards $4$ (or in your formulation of iterating $f_c=x^2-c$, as $c$ increases towards 2):
[image: Logistic Map]

Comment: Fascinating! Do you think this method can be adapted for $f(x)=x^2-c$, where $c$ is some positive real other than $1$?

Comment: Yes and no. It will work for many $c$, but I would expect some to be quite a bit trickier, particularly as you approach $c=2$; the structure of the attracting cycle can get much more complicated. This is, as I alluded to in a comment above, closely coupled to the structure of the Mandelbrot set along the real axis; for instance, the points in the 'big cardioid' correspond to an attracting fixed point, while the ones in the first circle to the left of that (in your formulation,larger $c$) correspond to an attracting 2-cycle. As your $c$ approaches 2 I _think_ you'll find some period doubling...

Comment: The discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Main_cardioid_and_period_bulbs is germane, and may serve as a jumping-off point for more information...

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll certainly look into it some more